# Android Device Monitor crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I use Android Studio and Android SDK Tools revision 23.0.2. I want to export a database from the phone but Android Device Monitor crashes each time. Before updating Android SDK Tools to revision 23.0.2 I was receiving "hprof-conv not present" error when opening Android Device Monitor, not being able to use it all.